# settings for REST in CF Administrator

Tags: rest, web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am trying to create a REST API in ColdFusion 10. I have created a coldfusion component with a function inside it.

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="restService">
    <cffunction name="sayHello" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET">        
          <cfset rest = "Hello World">
          <cfreturn rest>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

[image: CF Administrator settings]

Now I wanted to register my component in CF Administrator, so I have given the path to my cfc[D:/wwwroot/used_adm/cfc/resttest] in Root Path section. I wanted to understand what to give in service mapping   **http://ipaddressOfMyServer:portNo/rest/{servicemappping}/restService**  here I couldn’t understand what is {service mapping}? What should I mention for my application? Is it path to cfc again?

**Edit:**
In application.cfc I added the code below to make the CFC rest enable:

<cfset
restInitApplication("D:\wwwroot\used_adm\cfc\resttest","test") >

I am using this name "test" as a service mapping in ColdFusion administrator.

Then I tried to hit *http://domainName:portNo/rest/test/restService and getting page not found error.

In application.log I could see this error.

"Error","ajp-bio-8013-exec-1","09/29/21","00:34:43","TestProc","Instance of Component used_adm.cfc.resttest.PostTestReq could not be created.''. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\wwwroot\used_adm\cfc\resttest\postTestReq.cfc, line: 115 "
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: This will get you started.  https://www.cfguide.io/coldfusion-administrator/server-settings-mappings/

Comment: @DanBracuk  Can you help me to resolve this error if you know anything about this: "Error","ajp-bio-8013-exec-1","09/29/21","00:34:43","TestProc","Instance of Component used_adm.cfc.resttest.PostTestReq could not be created.''. The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\wwwroot\used_adm\cfc\resttest\postTestReq.cfc, line: 115 "

Comment: @SOS do you know anything about this?

Comment: Has the topic changed?  Were you able to solve the original problem of registering your cfc as a REST service?

Comment: yes @DanBracuk , I could register the service now. but not able to get correct result when I try to hit http://domainName:portNo/rest/test/restService, I'm getting 404 error and I application logs I could see the error I mentioned above. Not sure why is it happening.

Comment: You should answer this question with whatever you did to solve the first problem,  Then ask a new one for the next problem.  As you are composing the next question, try simple things like using `createobject()` or `<cfinvoke>` to access your cfc.

Comment: See this documentation - [Publishing web services](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/using-web-services/publishing-web-services.html)

Comment: @Miguel-F I followed your documentation, I could see the WSDL generated by postTestReq.cfc in the browser but when I try to output it on the webapp I'm getting an error saying:

Comment: 11:39:36.036 - Application Exception - in java/lang : line -1      coldfusion.jsp.CompilationFailedException: Errors reported by Java compiler: C:/ColdFusion10/cfusionstage/stubs/WS-31897119_2/src/cfc/Document.java:18: cannot access java.lang.Object
bad class file: java/lang/Object.class(java/lang:Object.class)

Comment: class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
        public  class Document
                ^